# Repeat a formula as much as there are filled cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

| Date1 | Date 2 | DatediffFormula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/03/2022 | 22/03/2022 | =DATEDIFF(A2;B2;"yd") |
| 14/03/2022 | 22/03/2022 | =DATEDIFF(A3;B3;"yd") |

I've been wondering how to automatically apply the upside formula DateDiff automatically, as much as there are filled cells in columns "Date1" and " Date2".

Should I do a VBA code or does an Excel Formula exist to solve this ?

I tried to add the following Excel formula that is based on : counting cells first and then return the number of cells ( from COlumns " Date1" and "Date2") to repeat "DateDiff" as many time, but it didnt work;

```
= DATEDIFF(OFFSET(C2;0;0;E2);A2;B2;"yd")
```

^C2 contains the excel formula "COUNTIF" that helps me to count the number of filled cells beside the column "DatediffFormula"

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Use a table (Ctrl+T).

Comment: I did Edit the post, sorry about it. What do you mean by  Using a table, please?

Comment: Convert your data into a table, making sure that you use a [calculated column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8) for your datedif column.